# How to dd an image and save it to tftp without saving into local machine?

Tags: linux, dd, remote, tftp, arch-arm

I want dd an image and save it to remote using tftp for example I'm trying to do

```
"dd if=/dev/mtd2" | save it to tftp server.
```

the direction of the file I have used in that code is wrong I'm trying my best to learn how it can be, this is the wrong code I made my self I mean half of it :'(

```
"dd if=/dev/mtd2" | tftp -l -p RootFS.bin 10.10.233.238 | dd of=File.bin
```

`

also if it's possible to transfer multiple folders and save it as one file on tftp for e.g I want to copy given below

`/ #`

or these directories

`bin   dev   etc   lib   mnt   opt   proc  root  sbin  sys   tmp   usr   var`

and save it as

`fielname.bin`

on

`tftp server`

My wrong code is

> tftp -l /bin && /dev/ && /etc/ && /lib/ && /mnt/ && /opt/ && /proc/ &&
>   /root/ && /sbin/ && /sys/ && /tmp/ && / usr/ && /var/ -r Linux.bin -p
>   10.10.233.238

Comment: Dear Can you mention the command for multiple directories transfer at once also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky one, and it also appears you're using an embedded device (by the use of /dev/mtd).

It looks like you're trying to take an image of a block device, and create a 'bin' file on another machine.  You may be overthinking this - a block device is openable as a file, and can be read by normal tools.

If that is what you are trying to achieve, the command you want to run is

`tftp -l /dev/mtd2 -r file.bin -p 10.10.233.238`

This opens the file /dev/mtd2 (even though it's a block device) and saves it as 'file.bin' on 10.10.233.238.

Comment: Dear check the question again and see I've change it to /dev/mtd2 as I mistakenly use the wrong name before. Plz also check this

http://www.satsig.net/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.pl?num=1249745511

Comment: I updated it, but the concept is the same - you can tread /dev/mtd2 as a file. There is no need to dd  it.